# Adding elements of entity to the same - @OneToMany

Tags: java, json, arraylist, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have the `Task` entity expressed as:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;
    @OneToOne
    private Employee assignee;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Task> precedingTasks;
    private String details;
    private int estimatedTimeInMinutes;
    private LocalDateTime deadline;
    private LocalDateTime creationTime;
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    private LocalDateTime endTime;

    public Task(String name, Category category, Employee assignee, List<Task> precedingTasks, String details,
                int estimatedTimeInMinutes, LocalDateTime deadline) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.assignee = assignee;
        this.precedingTasks = precedingTasks;
        this.details = details;
        this.estimatedTimeInMinutes = estimatedTimeInMinutes;
        this.deadline = deadline;
        this.creationTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.startTime = null;
        this.endTime = null;
    }
```

I noticed that tasks without `precedingTasks` are added correctly, but with not.

For example: after adding three tasks without `precedingTasks` I send `POST` in Postman as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Wyslac przesyłke nr 87",
    "category": "TODO",
    "assigneeId": 1,
    "precedingTasksId": [1, 2, 3],
    "details": "Dodac zakladke",
    "estimatedTimeInMinutes": 78,
    "deadline": "2013-12-18T14:30:40.100000000"
}
```

But I get a task without `preceding tasks`:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Wyslac przesyłke nr 87",
    "category": "TODO",
    "assignee": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Wojciech",
        "lastName": "Wasilewski",
        "email": "wojtek@wasilewski.pl",
        "role": "ADMIN",
        "password": "h*n$GvFE",
        "manager": true,
        "password_LENGTH": 8,
        "passwordValid": false
    },
    "precedingTasks": [],
    "details": "Dodac zakladke",
    "estimatedTimeInMinutes": 78,
    "deadline": "2013-12-18T14:30:40.1",
    "creationTime": "2018-08-01T13:38:45.924",
    "startTime": null,
    "endTime": null
}
```

I use this controller:

```
@PostMapping("/tasks")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Task addNewTask(@RequestBody TaskRequest taskRequest) {
    String name = taskRequest.getName();
    Category category = taskRequest.getCategory();
    checkIfAssigneeExists(taskRequest.getAssigneeId());
    Employee assignee = employeeRepository.findById(taskRequest.getAssigneeId()).get();
    List<Task> precedingTasks = new ArrayList<>();

    if (taskRequest.getPrecedingTaskIds() != null)
        taskRequest.getPrecedingTaskIds().forEach(id -> precedingTasks.add(taskRepository.findById(id).get()));

    String details = taskRequest.getDetails();
    int estimatedTimeInMinutes = taskRequest.getEstimatedTimeInMinutes();
    LocalDateTime deadline = taskRequest.getDeadline();
    Task task = new Task(name, category, assignee, precedingTasks, details, estimatedTimeInMinutes, deadline);
    taskRepository.save(task);
    return task;
}
```

And such a request:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaskRequest {

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    private Category category;

    @NonNull
    private Long assigneeId;

    @NonNull
    private List<Long> precedingTaskIds;

    private String details;
    private int estimatedTimeInMinutes;

    @NonNull
    private LocalDateTime deadline;
}
```

What is wrong? The contorller, or format of ArrayList in JSON? Should I add `precedingTasks` to the database before adding whole Task?

Comment: you need to add CascadeType. `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` on precedingTasks

Comment: @pvpkiran Thank you for your reply, but the result is still the same  :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field **precedingTaskIds** in your class **TaskRequest** does not correspondent by name to the one in your POST-request **precedingTasksId**. Rename it or rewrite POST in Postman.

Comment: That would explain why the tests were passing :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You POST "precedingTasksId" but the class expects "precedingTasksIds".

Seems like it's just a typo.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't noticed that before. Thank you for your help, but Maxim was
a little quicker to get "the best answer" ; )

Comment: Haha. No problem. I didn't saw his answer. Glad you got your answer. :)